# Group by query with rollup

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm trying to make a query that shows me every region and then make a count to see how mano contracts I have per region, but somehow I'm getting an error on `ROLLUP (BO2.area)`

This is the query

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN BO2.area IS NULL THEN ISNULL(BO2.area, 'TOTAL') ELSE BO2.area END Area,
  COUNT(BO.status = 'INSTALLED') Contracts
FROM
  BO2
  JOIN BO ON BO.bostamp = BO2.bo2stamp
GROUP BY
  ROLLUP (BO2.area)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should use [GROUPING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=GROUPING%20%28Transact-SQL%29%201%20Syntax.%20To%20view%20Transact-SQL%20syntax,GROUPING%20SETS%20from%20standard%20null%20values.%20%20) instead of a null check, and inside the aggregate you need a CASE expression.  So:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN GROUPING(BO2.area)=1 THEN 'TOTAL' ELSE BO2.area END Area,
  SUM( CASE WHEN BO.status = 'INSTALLED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Contracts
FROM
  BO2
  JOIN BO ON BO.bostamp = BO2.bo2stamp
GROUP BY
  ROLLUP (BO2.area)
```

Answer (score 0):

your query fails because Area is number (I'm guessing)  and you want to combine it to text , so you need to cast it to string:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN GROUPING(BO2.area)=1 THEN (cast(BO2.area as varchar(100)),'TOTAL') ELSE BO2.area END as Area
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN BO.status = 'INSTALLED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Contracts
FROM
  BO2
  JOIN BO ON BO.bostamp = BO2.bo2stamp
GROUP BY
  ROLLUP (BO2.area)
```

Comment: `BO2.area` is actually text, it show "Center", "North" and "South"

Comment: @pauLo_0liveira then what's the error message you are getting?